# WMI ThreadsPerHost Quota exceeded

Tags: windows, powershell, wmi

I have a server that is having application issues that seems to align with WMI showing the ThreadsPerHost quota was exceeded. Is there a way to tell what processes are keeping WMI threads open?

I tried wmic process list but that appears to simply show all open processes not those associated with or making calls to WMI.